# How can I make a smooth curve logistic line in R?

Tags: r

I am working on LT50 values and I want to visualize it in using the library MASS.

This is my working code

```
library(MASS)
dp<-read.csv("Diaporthe_2.7xLT.csv")
attach(dp)
y = cbind(Alive,Dead)
model.results = glm(y~Time,binomial)
summary(model.results)
dose.p(model.results,p=0.5)
model.results = glm(y~log(Time),binomial)
model.results
plot(log(Time),(Dead / (Alive + Dead)), ylab = "% Mortality")
logisticline = function(z) {
  eta = 23.616 + -4.477 * z;
  1 / (1 + exp(-eta))
  }

x = seq(2.0,5.5,0.001)
lines(x,logisticline(x),new = TRUE)
abline(v=4.072377,lty=2)
abline(h=0.5,lty=2)

## Take note that this is for the pure values
plot(Time, (Dead / (Alive + Dead)), ylab = "Proportional Mortality")
logisticline = function(z) {
  eta = 23.616 + -4.477 * z;
  1 / (1 + exp(-eta))
  }

x = seq(20, 160, 1.0)

lines(x, logisticline(x), new = TRUE)
```

[enter image description her](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sc2Ft.png) This is the plot that is viewed

I want to get the right x values seq to make the logline smooth

Comment: Can you post sample data? Please edit the question with the output of `dput(dp)`.